# Append build number to maven artifact when it's uploaded to Artifactory

Tags: maven, artifactory

I have created a local maven repo with the following configuration -
[image]

Now when I upload and artifact using `mvn deploy` the artifacts (a .zip package and a POM file) are uploaded with their names appended with the timestamp and a number as a suffix. I want to know what these single digit numbers at the very end are. Can I control them? Can I have say build numbers at the end instead of these auto generated numbers.

Please note that I want to replace the single digits after the timestamp with build numbers.

Cheers

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The format of Snapshot numbers is fixed and cannot be changed.

If you need a custom number format, you need to construct it yourself, e.g. you can use version numbers of the form `1.2.3-${buildnumber}`, but they will not be Snapshots in the sense of Maven.